# Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'. ReactTypescript by passing state setter as props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-state

I am passing a state prop from parent to child:

**Parent:**

```
const [refresh, setRefresh] = React.useState<boolean>(true);
```

passing into Component as

```
<Chart setRefresh={setRefresh}/>
```

**Child**

```
interface IChart {
    refreshChart?: boolean;
    setRefresh?: (newRefresh: boolean) => void;
}

const Chart: React.FunctionComponent<IChart> = ({refreshChart, setRefresh}) => {

   const handleRefresh = () => {
      setRefresh(false);
   }

}
```

Obviously it's to do with the type in the IChart interface as if I use `any` or not make it optional it works, but I need it optional and want to avoid any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Obviously it's to do with the type in the IChart interface as if I use any or not make it optional it works, but I need it optional and want to avoid any.

If you want to keep the property optional, then you have to deal with the fact it's optional, either by making the call to it check first:

```
const Chart: React.FunctionComponent<IChart> = ({refreshChart, setRefresh}) => {
    const handleRefresh = () => {
        if (setRefresh) {         // ***
            setRefresh(false);
        }
    };
}
```

...or by having a default:

```
const Chart: React.FunctionComponent<IChart> = ({refreshChart, setRefresh = (b: boolean) => {}}) => {
//                                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    const handleRefresh = () => {
        setRefresh(false);
    };
}
```

You might even make creating `handleRefresh` conditional based on whether `setRefresh` exists, and possibly even change what the component renders (e.g., no refresh UI) if `setRefresh` isn't provided.

Answer (score 1):

it's because in `IChart` interface you're saying that this property is optional, so it is "possibly undefined". Just remove "?" from `setRefresh` if the value is required.

Comment: The OP said: *"...but I need it optional..."*

Answer (score 1):

I do with Similar cases a simple `if condition` basically because if tweak it a teammate may come in the future and integrate it wrongly, or add a default value to it

```
 const handleRefresh = () => {
     if(setRefresh)
      setRefresh(false);
   }
```